# Can't start searchkick reindex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

I can’t start reindexing, and can’t connect the elasticsearch from rails app.

```
pry(main)> Searchkick.server_version
ETHON: Libcurl initialized
ETHON: performed EASY effective_url= response_code= return_code=url_malformat total_time=
ETHON: performed EASY effective_url= response_code= return_code=url_malformat total_time=
ETHON: performed EASY effective_url= response_code= return_code=url_malformat total_time=
ETHON: performed EASY effective_url= response_code= return_code=url_malformat total_time=
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
from /Users/superchel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/adapters/faraday.rb:106:in `block in request'
```

but curl connects without problems

`% curl localhost:9200/_cat/health                                 1648594087 22:48:07 elasticsearch_superchel green 1 1 3 3 0 0 0 0 - 100.0%`

please tell me what is the problem?
my system MacOS Monterey M1 chip

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

the problem was solved by updating the ethon gem from 0.12.0 to 0.15.0 version

```
bundle update ethon
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had to spend a couple of days on the same issue, finally came across your answer and it was the only thing that helped. Thank you!

Comment: This answer helped me identifying what was the issue for me. I had to update `typhoeus` from `1.3.0` to `1.4.0` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your search server URL? From https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#deployment

> For the search server, Searchkick uses ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"] for Elasticsearch and ENV["OPENSEARCH_URL"] for OpenSearch.

Comment: yes, I tried several  ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200, ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://0.0.0.0:9200 and ELASTICSEARCH_URL=127.0.0.1:9200, but it did not work

Comment: have you tried using URL syntax, like `http://localhost:9200`?